# CSS - Nested transitions

Tags: css, css-transitions

I am trying to use css transitions like this:

**On Hover** - Height transition is triggered then width transition is triggered

**When you mouse away** - Width transition is triggered then height transition is triggered

Here is example code:

```
#example {
width:100px;
height:100px;

background:#000000;
}

#example:hover {
width:200px;
height:200px;
}
```

Is there a way to use css transitions to get the desired effect?

Comment: Not that I know. Maybe with some clever animations, but I think you'll need JavaScript for that in any case.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha Thats what I thought, thanks anyway

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `transition-delay`. Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/S6Bt5/.

It's the best thing you can do with pure CSS. I think it'snot perfect becuase the delay is fixed, so using JS seems to be a slightly better idea…

Comment: Can you look on this and tell me why with my method after playing animation width and height back to start dimensions? http://jsfiddle.net/xwJAp/

Comment: @WooCaSh Hm, no, sorry, I'm not really familiar enough with CSS animations yet.